# `ddev get --list` doesn't work (lookup api.github.com: i/o timeout)

Tags: ddev

I need to add Solr to a DDEV project but am encountering errors when attempting to gather information about available services.

I'm following guidance here:
https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/additional-services/

When I attempt to list all available services: `ddev get --list`, I receive this response after approx 30 seconds:

```
Failed to list available add-ons: Unable to get list of available services: Get "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:ddev-get+fork:true+org:drud": dial tcp: lookup api.github.com: i/o timeout
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. If I curl the URL from the error message, ie `curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:ddev-get+fork:true+org:drud`, I receive a JSON response from Github with information about the repository.

This has happened for over two days now. I may be overlooking something but am not sure what, exactly. I'm able to run DDEV projects using the standard installation (mariadb, nginx, nodejs, mailhog) but continue to run into errors re listing add-ons.

I have ddev v.1.21.4 installed.

I'm using an M1 Mac on macOS 13.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is unable to do a DNS lookup of the hostname `api.github.com`, and this is happening on your macOS host. Are you able to `ping api.github.com`? Have you tried rebooting?

You may want to temporarily disable firewall, VPN, virus checker to see if that changes things. But you'll want to be able to get to where you can `ping api.github.com`.

There is an [obscure golang problem on macOS affecting situations where people have more than one DNS server](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/4443), so that could be it if you're in that category. You also might want to consider changing the DNS server for your system to 1.1.1.1, as this can sometimes be a problem with your local DNS server (but of course the fact that you can curl the URL argues against that).

Comment: This is working for me now @rfay. Yep I'd tried a reboot and connected to different networks. I reset my VPN and afterwards I'm able to run the commands successfully! I appreciate your assistance, thank you.